# can one controller send the user to another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am really new to CodeIgniter.

I am trying to setup a website where the user must be logged in to view the pages. Coming from Java, I am taking the hierarchical approach to things.

My thought was to write my own Controller base:

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
function  Controller()
{
    parent::Controller();

    if(!$this->quickauth->logged_in())
    {
    //they need to login, send them to the login page.
    }
}
}
?>
```

Now I can write controllers which extend it and I will be sure that they will always be logged in.

Here is the outline for the login page:

```
<?php
class login extends Controller
{
function index()
{
        //Lets just double check, they might not have to login.
    if ($this->quickauth->logged_in())
    {
    //send them to the main controller
    }
}
}
?>
```

Well as you can see I have gotten this far. What do I need to replace:
1. //send them to the main controller
2. //they need to login, send them to the login page.

with?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Blake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection is easy.

Just use:

```
redirect('controller/method');
```

Yes, load the url helper to access the redirect function.

```
$this->load->helper('url);
```

Since the url helper is used a lot, you should autoload it in config/autoload.

Comment: The better practise is to set some user status variables in your MY_Controller such as is_logged_in. Then in each extended controller's constructor, check if they are logged in. This enables you to let a user who is not logged in access the controller if it's ok for them to do so: some of your controllers will be ok for non-logged in users.

Comment: Duh. I must have been out last night when I wrote this. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

if you load the 'url_helper' you've got a redirect function in there. Read the docs about the [url helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use soemthing like this

```
function is_logged_in()
{
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if (!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) 
    {
     echo 'You don't have permission to access this page. <a href="http://lemonrose.net">Login</a>';
        die();
        //$this->load->view('login_form');
    }
}
```

You could build on this